# How to center a button in jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a simple counter app using jetpack compose  and want , button to be placed in center of the layout , i tried using Modifier.gravity(Alignment.Center) , but its not providing any result , what should be the way to implement this ?

Comment: What is the "layout"?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti , the layout is simply a button in center of the app , nothing else and the value of button updates when clicked , i have achieved the updating of value but don't know hoe to center the button in the layout , tried using Modifier.gravity but it didn't work

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Button(onClick = {})
    { Text("BUTTON") }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware that doing this the component, in this case the button, will hold all the avaliable area of the screen. Then if you need to positionate something, e.g., below the button it will not be shown once it will stay out of the screen.

Comment: If you want to put some other composables under the button, then add them in the same column under the button and they will show.  If you want to add something outside of the column, then you need first to remove Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight().